# Duplicate files copied in APK log4j2.xml can't figure out what to exclude

Tags: java, duplicates

When I try to run my app I keep getting this error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK log4j2.xml
>
> File1:
>   /Users/matti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.biojava/biojava-core/4.2.0/a0713c21c575f39adc88985acc9cf37715324dab/biojava-core-4.2.0.jar
>
> File2:
>   /Users/matti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.biojava/biojava-phylo/4.2.0/a97ccd582c87683d0e91e9fefb176ae129a10318/biojava-phylo-4.2.0.jar
>
> File3:
>   /Users/matti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.biojava/biojava-structure/4.2.0/2da167b09a829735f38379c3ad3c922c09a0a312/biojava-structure-4.2.0.jar
>
> File4:
>   /Users/matti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.biojava/biojava-alignment/4.2.0/6395347f4c119d6a41b850dbb84ba85919976d37/biojava-alignment-4.2.0.jar

How do I exclude these files?

Comment: You have dependencies which can cause this behavior.

Comment: @ssc these dependencies seem to be in the `WhereIsYourCode` class.

Answer (score -1):

i've encoutered similar issue when trying to use Log4j2 in android studio. each time i tried to run apk - build failed on a different file duplicate. 
i ended up doing this:

in build.gradle (app module):

add the following:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '<name_of_file_to_exclude>'
}
```

where the '' is extracted each time from the log error messages. i took me a lot of iterations, each time added 1 more file - but after a while i was finally able to install the apk.

Example:

for error msg:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/io.logz.sender/logzio-sender/pom.properties
```

you need to add:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/io.logz.sender/logzio-sender/pom.properties'
}
```